# iOS jailbreak console application, entitlements

Tags: ios, jailbreak, iphone-privateapi, entitlements, code-signing-entitlements

I'm running iOS 7 on a jailbroken iPhone, i'm attempting to create a console based application that can record audio. Trouble is that the microphone doesn't seem to be authorised (presumably because the user can't allow access).

From research it says that I can override this by setting the following in an entitlements file:

```
<key>com.apple.private.tcc.allow</key>
<array>
    <string>kTCCServiceMicrophone</string>
</array>
```

Does anyone have an example of the a fully populated entitlements file? I've been trying to do it and then using ldid to 'assign' them to the console app.

At the moment i'm at a loss and the application just creates an audio file with no content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to figure this out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.private.tcc.allow</key>
    <array>
        <string>kTCCServiceMicrophone</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Then just had to run the code signing utility on the product and copy it over to the device

Comment: How did you figure this out?

Comment: @newenglander sorry this was a while ago and I can't remember. Shouldn't be too hard to find.. looks like it took me under 2 hours :)